# AirPort Extreme Refusing Internet Connection to Windows Clients

Tags: network, airport, internet

I have an AirPort Extreme (3rd generation) acting as the router in the house. Unlike the Actiontec router that it replaced, Windows 7 (but not XP) computers connected to the LAN in various ways, either by wired ethernet or wireless-N, cannot access the Internet through it. I can ping them from my Mac on the LAN, but they cannot ping anything on the Internet like 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS). It can't be a DNS issue. I've tried both DHCP and manual setup, mimicking the settings my Mac uses except with a different IP address. I'm no expert at networking, so I don't know what else could cause it. What's going on?

I've switched between this router and the Actiontec in the past. Whenever this router is in, Windows 7 can't connect. The moment I switch to the Actiontec, it works.

Comment: need bit more info, like are you using the 802.11n ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 The 3rd generation AirPort Extreme supports draft 802.11n (as well as legacy g, a, b). If you mean to ask whether my Windows computers are using 802.11n to connect to the LAN: Sometimes they connect to wireless 802.11n access points (usually a few AirPort Expresses) that go through a switch before reaching the router, and sometimes they connect through ethernet cables that go through that same switch. No PC goes directly to the router, wired or wireless.